# Fast calculation for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2+1}dx=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2+1}dx=0$, but is there a faster method than finding the contour and doing all computations?

Otherwise my idea is to do the substitution $x=e^t$, integral than changes to $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t e^t}{1+e^{2t}}dt$. Next step is to take the contour $-r,r,r+i\pi,-r+i\pi$ and integrate over it...

Comment: did you try expanding the Geometric series $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{2k}$?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625360/slightly-tricky-integral (but Martin Agerami's answer here is very nice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general approach. Consider the integral

$$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sin(s\pi/2)},\quad 0<Re(s)<2. $$

which is the Mellin transform of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Now, our integral can be evaluated as

> $$ I = \lim_{s\to 1} F'(s) = 0.$$

**Note:**

1. To evaluate the above integral, you can use the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).
2. 

> $$ F(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x)dx \implies  F'(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}\ln(x)f(x)dx .$$

Comment: Thanks, this helped me since I evaluated the above integral already.

Comment: @UlrichOtto: Good job. Note that, this is a general integral which can be used to handle harder problems.

Comment: This is a good answer. If you included this level of detail to all your answers, we would avoid many disappointments. +1

Answer (score 18):

If you use the substitution $x=1/t$, you can check directly that
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\log t}{1+t^2}\,dt.
$$

Comment: or just $\int_0^\infty$ on both sides directly

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $x=\tan\theta$.

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\tan\theta)\,d\theta=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan\theta)\,d\theta=0$$