# How to evaluate the integral$ \frac{\log x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How might I evaluate this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log\ x}{1+x^2}dx$$

I tried substituing $x = \tan\ v$ but that didn't get me anywhere. Any suggestions as to a thought process for this one?

Answer (score 5):

Break up the integral into two pieces:

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2} + \int_1^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{1+x^2}$$

Sub $x=1/y$ in the second integral and see that the sum of the above integrals, and hence the original integral, is zero.

Comment: thats really clever! is there is a reasoning behind why you split the integral up?

Comment: @kloptuy554: always a useful transformation when there is a quadratic in the denominator.  Really even more useful when there is a log.

Comment: @kloptuy554: Please register. It 'll help you to trace your works here better. :-) and +1 for my friend Ron.